# Sorting Plotly bar chart data overlaid on candlestick chart

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am overlaying a barchart on a candlestick plot, all data is referenced from the same data frame. I want to sort the data ascending from the bar chart data but cannot find any guide to help with an overlay.
Has anyone gotten this to work? I've attached the current output but want the grey bars sorted.

```
O <- round(runif(62,-10,10),2)
H <- round(runif(62,-10,10),2)
L <- round(runif(62,-10,10),2)
C <- round(runif(62,-10,10),2)
LMA <- round(runif(62,-10,8),2)
OHLC <- data.frame(tick,O,H,L,C, LMA)
OHLC$ticker <- factor(OHLC$ticker, levels=unique(OHLC$ticker)[order(data$LMA)])
xform <- arrange(OHLC, LMA)

p<- plot_ly(xform, x=~tick, type="candlestick",
             open= ~O, close=~C, high=~H, low=~L) %>% 
  add_bars(x=~tick, y=LMA, marker = list(color = 'rgb(204,204,204)'))%>%
  add_lines(y=4, line = list(dash='dash'))%>%
  add_lines(y=-4, line = list(color='rgb(22, 96, 167)', dash='dash'))%>%
  layout(title="Title", showlegend=F)
p

dput(xform)
structure(list(tick = c("MBFI", "Y", "EV", "PACW", "NAVI", "NYCB", 
"RGA", "ASB", "DCT", "SEIC", "TCF", "WTFC", "MCY", "SBNY", "CATY", 
"KMPR", "FII", "PRI", "FHN", "CHFC", "TCBI", "WRB", "ORI", "PNFP", 
"SF", "SNV", "FAF", "TREE", "THG", "VLY", "WAFD", "FR", "PB", 
"FDS", "BOH", "BXS", "CFR", "IBKR", "IBOC", "FNB", "MKTX", "LM", 
"TRMK", "GNW", "WBS", "UMPQ", "BRO", "UBSI", "AFG", "EVR", "OZRK", 
"AHL", "PRSP", "CBSH", "CNO", "SLM", "STL", "FULT", "HOMB", "RNR", 
"UMBF", "EWBC"), O = c(-6.74, 8.06, -9.68, -6.02, 1.15, 2.91, 
-3.76, 6.24, -8.42, 6.98, 9.73, 8.88, -3.06, -8.61, -3.92, 8.47, 
-7.84, -5.91, -8.45, 1.37, -9.74, 4.26, 6.71, -7.17, 3.95, -9.01, 
1.56, -1.38, 4.01, -6.98, 2.77, 8.71, 3.76, 1.6, -3.32, -3.87, 
6.3, -9.02, 5.39, -1.37, -2.11, -8.3, 6.65, -5.33, -3.79, 8.63, 
-2.87, 7.57, 7.9, -0.27, 1.28, -7.68, -9.69, 2.35, 4.01, 2.36, 
-4.37, -1.54, -8.56, 0.98, -3.26, 7.26), H = c(-8.06, -1.24, 
-7.93, 7.3, 0.05, -8.75, -4.05, -6.87, -2.35, 0.34, -6.75, 2.6, 
-9.63, -1.82, 6.29, 0.79, 0.43, 6.23, -6.79, -9.23, 6.37, -3.2, 
-7.05, 1.14, -4.31, -1.04, 9.04, -4.33, -5.55, -7.21, 0.24, -3.1, 
-2.07, 1.07, -5.97, 5.27, 9.74, -3.03, -1.45, 0.34, -5.39, -9.1, 
6.12, 2.12, 2.01, 6.12, 0.7, -6.72, 2.54, -1.18, 1.42, -4.01, 
-1.03, -0.49, -8.09, 1.69, -3.35, 8.74, -7.29, 1.1, 6.4, -8.89
), L = c(-9.68, 4.91, -9.11, -4.65, 3.56, -4.67, -2.59, 0.66, 
-2.05, 9.44, 3.67, 6.25, 9.35, -9.31, -0.23, 9.56, 2, -9.9, 5.99, 
9.16, -0.79, 5.7, 2.22, -4.43, -9.53, -8.52, -0.23, -1.95, 8.29, 
-8.29, -9.25, 7.04, -5.39, -5.61, 5.6, 2.38, 8.72, -5.07, -4.11, 
-5.29, -4.7, 6.15, -3.52, -8.48, -9.06, 7.48, -0.06, 7.6, -1.2, 
-8.02, -3.91, 2.26, -6.21, -2.31, 5.74, 9.98, 4.91, -6.14, -6.66, 
7.31, -0.3, -5.72), C = c(-8.51, -3.3, -5.39, -0.09, -3.18, 9.1, 
-5.29, 0.39, -9.34, 1.79, -3.09, -2.33, -7.48, 7.39, -5.85, -2.95, 
-8.67, 8.61, 8.96, -1.02, -1.45, 5.18, -4.78, 5.41, 2.25, -0.26, 
1.04, 2.46, -3.95, -3.47, -8.46, 4.97, 8.7, 7.41, -4.07, -8.53, 
6.84, -8.9, 4.6, 4.07, 0.71, 4.02, 0.26, -9.55, -7.3, 4.33, -3.46, 
-1.55, -4.91, -7.87, 5.14, 2.56, 9.15, 1.07, 2.44, -2.75, 0.72, 
-9.93, -1.9, -4.03, -5.99, -2.23), LMA = c(-9.49, -9.22, -9.21, 
-9.19, -8.75, -8.49, -8.46, -7.99, -7.95, -7.86, -7.32, -7.09, 
-7, -5.96, -5.83, -5.77, -5.07, -4.78, -4.67, -4.62, -4.44, -4.18, 
-4.05, -3.06, -2.76, -2.72, -1.79, -1.03, -0.95, -0.85, -0.45, 
0, 0.14, 0.18, 0.53, 0.77, 0.98, 1.39, 2.32, 2.36, 2.48, 2.51, 
2.64, 2.95, 3.2, 3.25, 3.26, 3.61, 4.2, 4.29, 4.39, 4.45, 4.69, 
5.46, 5.72, 5.72, 5.78, 6.26, 6.34, 6.59, 6.83, 7.18)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-62L))
```

[image: Output]
[image: xform Output]

Comment: In your code `tick` and `ticker` objects are not defined.

Comment: I know, they are categorical variables of length 62 in this case.

Comment: Try transforming `tick` and `ticker` into character vectors: `OHLC$tick <- as.character(OHLC$tick)`. It works on my R with plotly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still get it displaying alphabetically even though xform is sorted ascending by LMA.

Comment: Please, could you share the output  of `dput(xform)` ?

Comment: Just added a screenshot and the code output for dput(xform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the categories on the x-axis can be controlled using `categoryorder` as follows:

```
p <- plot_ly(xform, x=~tick, type="candlestick",
             open= ~O, close=~C, high=~H, low=~L) %>% 
  add_bars(x=~tick, y=~LMA, marker=list(color='rgb(204,204,204)')) %>%
  add_lines(y=4, line=list(dash='dash')) %>%
  add_lines(y=-4, line=list(color='rgb(22, 96, 167)', dash='dash')) %>%
  layout(title="Title", showlegend=F, xaxis=list(categoryorder="trace"))
p
```

Possible options are `trace`, `category ascending`, `category descending`, `array` as described [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-categoryorder).

[image]